# How to modeling a program to understand easier

Tags: python, uml, modeling

I'm modifying a Python program suitable for my purpose. At first, I read the source code to know the class or function I think needed to change and then modify it. Now, I want to understand all the source code (just meaning, input, output of each function and class in program). So how could I modeling entire program, I know UML is for this purpose but I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the `python` world looks like.

In languages like `java` you'd ask your `IDE` to create some simplified model from the code for you. Or you'd use some [UML modeling tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) like Sparx Systems's Enterprise Architect and it's [reverse engineering features](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html) to create the initial `UML` model for you.

Once you have the initial `UML` model, keeping it updated and annotated with important things behind and above the code and envisioning changes is mostly language-agnostic manual task

See also:

- Scott W. Ambler's online book [Agile Modeling: Effective Practices for Modeling and Documentation](http://agilemodeling.com/)